# how to change ion-button menuToggle color?

Tags: html, ionic-framework

Here is the ionic code

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
<button ion-button menuToggle>
  <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
</button>
<ion-title style="text-align:left;">Handy Mandy</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

How do I change the whole bar color like steam application ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is confusing.  if you are talking about the whole toolbar you can set this variable `$toolbar-background` in your variables.scss

Comment: @PhilipBrack sorry, yeah. I want to change the toolbar color like the steam application, I don't know why my tool bar is default color as white and can't be change. I will try your solution now. Thanks !!

Comment: @PhilipBrack Thanks a lot !!! It works. OMG, it was wondering me the whole morning. Thank you so much. <3 !!!